# How can I remove characters that are not supported by MySQL's utf8 character set?

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8, utf8mb4

How can I remove characters from a string that are not supported by MySQL's [utf8 character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html)? In other words, characters with four bytes, such as "", that are only supported by MySQL's [utf8mb4 character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

For example,

```
C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰
```

should become

```
C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰
```

I want to load a data file into a MySQL table that has `CHARSET=utf8`.

Comment: I hear what you are asking, but why not convert the column to `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`?

Comment: utf8mb4 is preferred, if you don't want to damage data. utf8 is 2 bytes and just truncates the UTF-8 byte sequence, if I remember correctly.  BTW utf8mb4 is default in newer versions of MySQL. No need to configure it in `my.cnf`. MariaDB is different.

Comment: Check the column definitions of your DB-schema. If there still are some on utf8 (or Latin1?) convert them. Perl handles everything perfect if you `db_connect` with `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL's `utf8mb4` encoding is what the world calls `UTF-8`.

MySQL's `utf8` encoding is a subset of `UTF-8` that only supports characters in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (meaning characters U+0000 to U+FFFF inclusive).

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

So, the following will match the unsupported characters in question:

```
/[^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}]/
```

Here are three different techniques you can use clean your input:

1: Remove unsupported characters:

```
s/[^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}]//g;
```

2: Replace unsupported characters with U+FFFD:

```
s/[^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}]/\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}/g;
```

3: Replace unsupported characters using a translation map:

```
my %translations = (
    "\N{MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL EPSILON}" => "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON}",
    # ...
);

s{([^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}])}{ $translations{$1} // "\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}" }eg;
```

---

For example,

```
use utf8;                              # Source code is encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';   # Terminal and files use UTF-8.

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;               # say, //
use charnames ':full';   # Not needed in 5.16+

my %translations = (
   "\N{MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL EPSILON}" => "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON}",
   # ...
);

$_ = "C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰";
say;

s{([^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}])}{ $translations{$1} // "\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}" }eg;
say;
```

Output:

```
C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰
εC = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; εH = -57‰
```

Comment: If I understand right, I have to convert the utf8 characters (e.g. the 4 byte char "")  into BMP before applying your regex. Is there a function to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by converting "" into BMP. The BMP is a set of characters that doesn't include "". You could create a mapping of characters outside of the BMP to characters inside of the BMP. I've just added a demonstration of this to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I meant something else: I would like to remove the 4 byte utf8 chars by using your regex s/[^\N{U+0000}-\N{U+FFFF}]//g; However when I apply it to my file (which contains a "" instead of its BMP representation) the 4 byte chars are not filtered out.

Comment: Are you sure you have decoded text (as opposed to UTF-8)?

Comment: No, I think it's not decoded. How can I do this? For example my file contains this phrase "C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰"

Comment: For that to be possible, your source file would have to be encoded using UTF-8 and contain `use utf8;`. Is that the case?

Comment: I am little confused right now. Maybe you can give a explanation what I have to do with the file, after reading the text in to the memory?

Comment: You said you had `"C = -2.4‰ ± 0.3‰; H = -57‰"`. Now you say you are reading it from a file. You'll need to decode the file. You can specify an `:encoding` layer when you open the file, or you could use the `open` pragma as I did in the example I've added to my answer.

Comment: Now got it, with replacement is even better. Perfect. Thanks a lot!